# According to authoritative Catholic exegetes, does 2 Cor. 6:14 forbid Christians from working with non-Christians in the workplace?

Tags: catholicism, exegesis, paul-apostle, 2-corinthians

St. Paul, 2 Cor. 6:14:

> Bear not the yoke with infidels. For what participation hath justice with iniquity? or what society is there between light and darkness?

According to authoritative Catholic exegetes such as the Fathers of the Church,
does this forbid Christians from working with non-Christians in the workplace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

John Chrysostom is a 4th century Doctor of the Roman Catholic Church and he does not interpret the passage this way:

> He said not, 'Intermix not with unbelievers,' but rather dealing
>   sharply with them, as transgressing what was right, 'Suffer not
>   yourselves to turn aside,' says he, For what fellowship have
>   righteousness and iniquity?
>
> [*Homily XIII on the Second Epistle to the Corinthians*](http://www.newadvent.org/fathers/220213.htm)